Laravel Project work properly on localhost but not on planethoster server
I buld web site with laravel 10 and it work properly on localhost, but when I moved it to the planethoster server it shows:

page not found.

I made some changes in the .env file, such as the domain name and the database connection information. I moved the .htaccess file from the public folder to the root folder and modified the
"RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]"

to
"RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]".

However, when I tried to view the page via the domain name (domain.com), it redirected me to (domain.com/fr) with a 404 "page not found" error.
How can you help me, please?
I used Laravel 10 to build the website.
